# I'm working in a library system project but somehow when i run my code nothing shows up

Tags: python

here is the code :

```
foreverloop = 0
booklist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
while foreverloop <= 10:
    book = booklist
addorremove = input("Would you like to add/remove book?1 to add , 2 to remove,3 to remain the same")
if addorremove == 1:
    add = input("add book :")
    booklist.insert(0,add)
    print(book)
elif addorremove == 2:
    remove = input("remove book:")
    booklist.remove(remove)
    print (book)
elif addorremove ==3:
    borrow = input("Borrow book? 1 to borrow,2 to close programe")
    if borrow == 1:
        borrowsystem = input("Which book would you like to borrow ?")                   
        if borrowsystem in book:
            print("book succesfully borrowed!")
        else:
            print("Sorry,book not available in this library")
    elif borrow ==2:
        quit
```

i was expecting a syntax error or smt but nothing showed up pls help,suggestions are welcomed

Comment: I suggest that you familiarize yourself with this site before posting a question with "wasd" repeated a hundred times. Take the [tour] and read [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Put a little bit more effort into crafting your question.

Comment: Your indentation is just wrong. Your `while` loop only spans the one line immediately below it, turning it into an infinite loop. Your variable `foreverloop` lives up to its name.

Comment: Also, none of the `if..else` conditions will ever match, because you're comparing a string to numbers.

Comment: The reason nothing shows up is because of the infinite loop. Your loop body is 
`while foreverloop <= 10:
    book = booklist
`
Since varaible `foreverloop` is never modified, this loop will never exit. According to what I assume you want to do, 
1. you should move your `if statement` into loop body.
2. Use `int()` to transfer input string as a integer, otherwise `addorremove` will never equals to 1, 2, 3...

Comment: The linked duplicate is wrong IMHO. While that problem is also found in the code in question, it's the infinite loop that causes the program to get stuck. It doesn't even get to the issue of wrong input type.

Comment: @Friedrich Would you prefer to have this closed as a typo instead…?

Comment: @deceze that's what I voted for, so: yes. Although it's more like a basic syntax issue. Not a perfect fit, the dupe also isn't. This made me wonder if we're all a little too quick on the close button - especially with poorly researched questions.

Comment: @deceze I am really sorry to ping you ,may i ask for a solution? ive been working on this bug for a long time and i was using the tips i got on the internet (maybe i didnt read the most important parts or warnings).I am really grateful for you guys to spend your time to help a new person

Comment: and how do i make add at the 7th line to insert the books name

Comment: Have you read the comments above? Especially the one about the wrong indentation? Did you understand what is meant by that?

Comment: @deceze forgive me if i dont understand,but do u mean the 4 spaces after if and elif and else?

Comment: That's indentation, yes. And the *entire block* starting with `addorremove = ...` needs to be indented more to be inside the `while` loop. Indentation is very important in Python, and yours is apparently wrong.

Comment: I'd post the working code as part of an answer if this question gets reopened. There are a few small issues in there.

Comment: @deceze i just tried and it didnt work smhw ,do u meant by putting it in the next line  + 4 spaces after while ?

Comment: to reopen this question ,i need to edit it right ? pls do wait til tomorrow since I am busy with another school project ,forgive me for wasting yalls time for not understanding it as i am new from scratch to python so ... things kinda went wrong ;-;

Comment: @calcoolatorz there's not much you can do to get it reopened. It's already in the reopen queue and needs two more votes. No way to tell if and when they will come.

Comment: i fixed my bug by adding () such as if (addorremove==1)

Comment: The parentheses as you describe them have no effect. You must have changed something else as well. Anyway, glad you managed to fix an issue.

Comment: @Friedrich i have encountered a new bug about elif statement not working and no syntax error , and needed your help to fix it ,may ik how to notify u when i am available to make a new post ?

Comment: You can @tag me like you did. I'll try to help but you needn't rely on me alone. There's lots of other people who also answer your questions. Ask away, try to make your question focused and meaningful.

Comment: @friedrich does an if elif statement not showing syntax error not working with correct identation sounds good as a question ?

Comment: Just ask away. I can understand you being guarded considering the reactions to this question. Another thing, if if's a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), you should mention it.

Comment: @Friedrich , here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78213987/homeworkproblemmy-code-is-seemingly-alright-but-when-i-run-it-it-skips-some-l thankyou for using your time on my problems

Comment: @Friedrich can you show me and example of a good question? i tried minimizing my code and still got downvotes

Comment: i just needed to know whats wrong and only one person replied with nothing thats relating abt the title

Comment: @Friedrich sorry i mentioned u but i just want to tell you my father fixed the bug tysm

Comment: No problem at all. Sadly, SO isn't a very pleasant place for new users and novice programmers. This site expects users to be familiar with a language's basic features and having done some research before asking. You can always take your issue to [meta]. Although I should warn you to be prepared that people will mercilessly point to the weak spots in your questions. As for good questions, this site is full of them. Take a look at some with several upvotes.